# Laravel abort( 404 ) Throwing NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, error-handling, http-status-codes

When using the following Laravel helper function in a view:

```
abort( 404 );
```

Instead of displaying the default Laravel 404 error page, I'm getting:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
```

Stack Trace:

```
public function abort($code, $message = '', array $headers = [])

{

    if ($code == 404) {

        throw new NotFoundHttpException($message);

    }

    throw new HttpException($code, $message, null, $headers);

}
```

How can I get abort( 404 ); to display the stock Laravel 404 error page?

Comment: How come you're using it in a view and not the route callback/controller method?

Comment: That was it, thank you. I needed to call abort( 404 ) from my controller method instead of a view.

Comment: Never perform **any** logic in a view